# 401(k) non resident alien -early withdrawal penalty 10%

Tags: united-states, canada, 401k, non-resident, penalty

I have a  401(k) with over 100 k in it .

My question is if my former employer's 401(k) plan does not withhold the 10 % early withdrawal penalty, will I need to pay this with a US tax return ?  after or  is there any way the IRS  will ask for payment ?

Details:
The US employer   ''Separation of employment'' - termination due to  oilfield slowdown

- Can I claim ''hardship'' terms to  avoid the  10% penalty ?
- They will with-hold  15 % of the total with Canada tax treaty claim (not the standard 30 % )
- Canadian citizen - non -resident  of the  USA.
- Age 48
- No other USA income, other than a US stock brokerage account - as non resident.

Comment: You will be required to file a US tax return regardless. Withholding is just an approximation. You always need to file a return to calculate the exact amount, and will get a refund if you've paid too much, and need to pay more if you haven't paid enough.

Answer (score 1):

The 10% early withdrawal penalty is just that *a penalty*, not a withholding.  Your employer isn't responsible for dealing with it, it'll be assessed when you file your US taxes.

To your other question - it sucks for someone in that situation, but hardship is not one of the limited exceptions to the 10% penalty.